# Total Retention Rate Calculated from Categories

Tags: dataset, statistics, data, data-analysis, performance

I am calculating retention for 3 categories and then total, and I am trying to double check my total, but my check formula isn't working.

I am comparing the last 14 days (let's call it ***Period 1***) to the 14 days before that (let's call it ***Period 2***).
I am using the following formula:

[image]

I did it for each category and in total.

- **Category A**:

  - Users Period 1 = 9
  - New Users Period 1 = 4
  - Users Period 2 = 5
  - **Category A Retention = 100%**
  - (Total users = 9)
- **Category B**:

  - Users Period 1 = 12
  - New Users Period 1 = 5
  - Users Period 2 = 10
  - **Category B Retention = 70%**
  - (Total users = 15)
- **Category C**:

  - Users Period 1 = 2
  - New Users Period 1 = 2
  - Users Period 2 = 0
  - **Category C Retention = NA because no users in Period 2**
  - (Total users = 2)

Now to calculate the total I can do it directly doing:

- Users Period 1 = 23
- New Users Period 1 = 11
- Users Period 2 = 15
- **Total Retention = 80%**

However, I would like to calculate that also using the categories to double check the total. What I am currently doing is:

Note: I didn't include category C when calculating the weights because retention is not applicable because there were no users in period 2. So the weights are calculated as Category Users/(CatA+CatB Total Users)

[image]

Why is it not equal to .8? What am I doing wrong in this second method of calculating the total retention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the incorrect weights when combining the two categories. Instead of using the total users you should instead use the number of users in the second period to weigh the categories. This then also automatically removes category C from the equation since this category contains zero users in the second period.

$1 * (5 / 15) + 0.7 * (10 / 15) = 0.8$

Comment: Thank you so much! Are the rest of my calculations for retention correct?